# Symfony mobile responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have an issue with the mobile view of my webapp. the desktop version of my webapp is already finished and now i want to style the mobile view. As allways i use bootstrap and its default navbar but if i switch onto my smartphone it do not show me the mobile version of the navbar.

the whole website is like a small desktop view ... 
i know there is a mobile bundle but that cant be the solution ... on each other website bootstrap works well ...

Is there a spezial config to set?

[screenshot google chrome emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpm4S.png)

Comment: What this has to do with Symfony?

Comment: @emix I think it does not work because of symfony

Comment: How could symfony, as a server-side framework which does nothing but create a response from a request, be responsible for a css problem? This makes no sense really.

Comment: You have simple HTML/CSS issue in your templates.

Comment: @Yoshi yea your right. i forgot to add the viewport. (copy - paste mistake) unbelivable

Comment: @emix thx i fixed it ... thanks for help :)

Comment: @Corepex Would you please update your question to reflect that this had nothing to do with symfony, not that somebody reading this might get fooled.

Comment: @Yoshi done :D thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should make this line in the  of base.html.twig

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This will set the viewport of your page, which will give the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

Comment: thanks ... i can't believe that i forgot to add the viewport. unbelivable that i didnt noticed that.

sometimes it's the simple things ...